# PHPMailer using oauth2 gmail SMTP - how to prevent email from going to sent folder?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using Google's XOAuth2 SMTP authentication using the League OAuth2 client library. I don't want to store sent emails in the sent folder of gmail. The email sent successfully through gmail account and showing in sent items but I don't want to show in sent items. Let me know if there is method.

Here is my script.

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    try {
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
        $mail->isSMTP();                                     
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
        $mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
        $mail->Port = 587;                                   

        $email = '***@****.com';
        $clientId = '********************************************.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        $clientSecret = '*******************';
        $refreshToken = '*********************************************';
        $provider = new League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google(
            [
                'clientId' => $clientId,
                'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            ]
        );
        $mail->setOAuth(
            new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth(
                [
                    'provider' => $provider,
                    'clientId' => $clientId,
                    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
                    'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
                    'userName' => $email,
                ]
            )
        );

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($FromEmail,$FromName);

        if(is_array($to)){
            foreach($to as $eachEmail){
                $mail->addAddress($eachEmail);
            }
        }else{
            $mail->addAddress($to);
        }

        if($replyTo != ''){
            $mail->addReplyTo($replyTo);
        }else{
            $mail->addReplyTo($FromEmail);
        }

        if($bcc != ''){
            $mail->addBCC($bcc);
        }

        if(is_array($attachments) AND !empty($attachments)){
            foreach($attachments as $File){
                $mail->addAttachment($File); 
            }
        }else if($attachments != ''){
            $mail->addAttachment($attachments);
        }

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $message;
        $mail->send();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
       return false;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's appearing in your sent folder, it means gmail is putting a copy there, not your sending code. You could write a script that connects to your sent items folder over IMAP and deletes it afterwards, but that's beyond what PHPMailer does.